# Conservative vector field, potential function and work done

Tags: integration, vector-spaces, self-learning

[image]

For (i), is that I have to show $curl F = 0$ ?

For (ii) and (iii), what should I do in order to find the potential function and work done? Also, is the answer $4$ for (iii)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) That's correct.

(ii) You want $\nabla f = (2x \cos y -2z^3, 3 + 2ye^z-x^2\sin y,y^2e^z - 6xz^2) = F$. Then you need to integrate

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x \cos y -2z^3, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=3 + 2ye^z-x^2\sin y,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=y^2e^z - 6xz^2 $$ to find $f$.

(iii) Evaluate $\int F\dot \  dr = f(B) - f(A)$.

**Edit:** 
$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2x \cos y -2z^3 \Rightarrow \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx = \int  (2x \cos y -2z^3) dx \\&= x^2\cos y - 2x z^3 + g(y,z) \\ &\Rightarrow f(x,y,z) = x^2 \cos y  - 2x z^3 + g(y,z) \end{align}$$

Now you need to find the function $g(y,z)$, to do so derivate with respect to $y$ and compare to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. You need to do the same to the other partials.

Comment: @user110858 If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Why I have to integrate the above equations? I am still confused.

Comment: In order to find $f(x,y,z)$, we have by definition that $\nabla f = \langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \rangle$ and we want $\nabla f = F$.

Comment: So, is the answer $2xsinx +2cosx -2xz^3 +3y +y^2 e^z +x^2 cosy + Constant$ ?

Comment: You need to be careful, I'll do the first integration.

Comment: I think that $df/dx$ should be $2xcosy -2z^3$ instead of $2xcosx -2z^3$

Comment: @user100523 Thanks, I didn't see. That change things, I'm going to correct it.